# Point folder on main HDD to newly mounted 2nd HDD

Tags: linux, hard-disk, symlink, fstab

What is the best way to point a folder in one of my websites directory to a folder in a second HDD I just had installed? I see things about fstab and symlink but am lost at what is the best way to do it. My main HDD (sda) has almost filled up so I would like to move the uploads folder of one of my sites, which contains a few hundred GB of files, to the 2nd HDD (sdb). I want this folder to still be read and written to the same way it always has. Any ideas? Thanx

Comment: Do you also plan to put other data on the second HDD, or only the `uploads` directory?

Comment: Hi celtschk. At this stage I only want to put the uploads folder in the new HDD

Comment: Moving existing data, and then "pointing" a folder to a folder in the new disk are two operations. Make new folder, move existing data to new folder, then make old dir as symlink to new. Any app writing to existing folder will likely need to be paused or stopped and restarted as you will have to remove the existing directory to create the symlink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following, `LABEL` can be anything you want, `/dev/sdb1` is the partition you create and choose to use on your new HDD and `/var/www/myfiles` is where your files are currently located.  Alter these to suint your scenario.

1. Partition the new HDD.  You can have one partition that takes up the whole disk, or make a smaller partition which leaves you space on the HDD for other partitions at a later date. `gparted` is probably the easiest way to create partitions.
2. Create a filesystem on the new partition.  Name the **filesystem**.  The command needed to do this depends on which filesystem you choose to use.  If it's `ext2/3/4` then use the `e2label` command - eg `e2label /dev/sdb1 WebFiles`. Alternatively, `gparted` can add labels to a partition.
3. Mount the new partition on `/mnt` - `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`.
4. Move the data from the old directory to the new HDD - `mv /var/www/myfiles/* /mnt`. Note - move the files; don't copy them; as the copy command (`cp`) can change owners of files.
5. Unmount the new partition - `umount /mnt`.
6. Mount the new partition on the directory where the files should reside - `mount /dev/sdb1 /var/www/myfiles`.
7. If everything works, make this permanent by adding an entry to `/etc/fstab`:

   `LABEL=WebFiles /var/www/myfiles            ext4 defaults 1 2`
8. Unmount it - `umount /dev/sdb1`; then check it mounts automatically using the `fstab` entry - `mount -a`.

Hopefully, everything should work ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information garethTheRed, it helped a lot